# Direct3D vector output?

Tags: graphics, vector, direct3d, 3d, raster

Is there any means to interpret Direct3D output as a series of vectors instead of a raster image? I am hoping I could use such a feature to generate a PDF file containing the rendered Direct3D output. Am I being too optimistic?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is noting specifically stopping you from interpreting the input data as vectors.  It is, however, fundamentally a rasteriser.  Pixel shaders entirely stop making sense the moment you convert to vector data.

Still you know what your transforms are and you know what the vertex data is so you could output it as vector data in whatever format you want ...